# Glossed examples in a fancytikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters, linguex

I am making a poster using the class fancytikzposter. The problem is that when I include glossed examples in the poster with the linguex commands, the first two lines (the sentence in the language and the gloss) are very tiny and the translation line appears as normal as you can see on the picture. But I would like the glossed examples to appear normally. Please help me.

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\usetemplate{2}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{008888} 
\setfirstcolor{orange}% default 116699
\setsecondcolor{white!80}% default CCCCCC
\setinnerblocktitlefillcolor{gray}
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[style=langsci-unified, natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\initializesizeandshifts
\titleblock{50}{1}
\blocknode{Introduction}{

\innerblockplain[gray]{
\ex. \ag. mi che \\
I leave\\
\glt I am leaving\\


}}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The `fancytikzposter` package is very old and unmaintained, and has been merged with the `tikzposter` class, which itself is quite old. I would recommend using `tcolorbox` and its `[poster]` option along with the `fontsize` package to manage font size.